# How to use v-for in script

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have map data that **only accepts sting values** and data has to be placed in script (*not allowed to pass data from template*).

And I have array of data that I wish to show in map bubble but for that I need to loop those data.

So far I can get my data but I'm unable to loop them.

## code

```
let defCores = el.cores;
let cores = []; // gives me array of data with variables of name and color
for(let i = 0; i < defCores.length; i++){
    cores.push({core:defCores[i].name, color:defCores[i].color})
}

// looping my data
const desc = "<div v-for="+ core in cores +">" + core.name + "</div>";

this.addMarkerToGroup(group, {lat:el.longitude, lng:el.latitude}, desc, map);
```

#### Error

Currently I'm getting:

> ReferenceError: core is not defined.

#### Question

How can I loop my `cores` data inside my `desc` variable in order to show them in maps?

Comment: Try appending the cores array to the Vue-instance

Comment: @PhilipF. how?.

Comment: e.g. var app = new Vue({el:'#yourElement', data: {cores: []}});
and then app.cores = cores;

Comment: @PhilipF. `#yourElement` is assigned to maps logic and my data is not only this `cores` there are several more i just remove them to make my code more clean for this question.

Comment: Next time please also add a "hello world" data example (Complete example). In this way, the question is less useful to future readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For looping the cores into a string:

```
let desc = ''

cores.forEach(core => {
  desc += "<div>" + core.core + "</div>"
}
```

Also pay attention that `core.name` is actually `core.core` within your code.